# System.LimitException: Too many callouts: 101 Error

Tags: apex, trigger, developer-console

I have this below code which is pushed to prod. Where in I am trying to make callout in future method to update lat/long values on Standard location Trigger, and each time the records are processed i am getting this error

```
Failed to invoke future method 'public static void updateLocation(String)' on class 'UpdateLocationAddress' for job id '7076e0000ETHyxB'
caused by: System.LimitException: Too many callouts: 101
Class.UpdateLocationAddress.updateLocation: line 31, column 1
```

i am getting almost 10-15 emails a day regarding this error

Please find my code below

```
public class UpdateLocationAddress {
   
    @future(callout=true)
    public static void updateLocation(String locationlist){
        List<Schema.Location> updatedLocationList = (List<Schema.Location>)JSON.deserialize(locationlist, List<Schema.Location>.class);
             List<Schema.Location> locList = new List<Schema.Location>();
            List<String> locationId = new List<String>();
            for(Schema.Location loc:updatedLocationList){
                locationId.add(loc.Id);
            }
            List<Schema.Location> updatedLocList = updatedLocationList; //[Select Id,Zip_Postal_Code__c,Country__c,State_Province__c,Street__c,City__c from Location where Id IN: locationId];
           
            for(Schema.Location locat:updatedLocList){
                
                String geocodingKey = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';
                // Create and add an address.
                String salesforceAddress = locat.Street__c+', '+locat.City__c +', '+locat.State_Province__c+', '+locat.Zip_Postal_Code__c+', '+locat.Country__c;
                // String salesforceAddress = '415 Mission Street, San Francisco, CA 94105 USA';
                System.debug(geocodingKey);
                String geoAddress= EncodingUtil.urlEncode(salesforceAddress, 'UTF-8');
                System.debug(geoAddress);
                //make the callout to the Geocoding API
                Http http = new Http();
                HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
                request.setEndpoint('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address='+geoAddress +'&key='+ geocodingKey+'&sensor=false');
                request.setMethod('GET');
                request.setTimeout(60000);
                try {
                    // make the http callout
                    HttpResponse response = http.send(request);
                    system.debug('@@response'+response);
                    system.debug('@@response.getBody()'+response.getBody());
                    res resData = (res) System.JSON.deserialize(response.getBody(), res.class);
                    System.debug('Lat@@@' + resData.results[0].geometry.location.lat);
                    System.debug('lng@@@' + resData.results[0].geometry.location.lng);
                    locat.latitude = decimal.valueOf(resData.results[0].geometry.location.lat);
                    locat.longitude = decimal.valueOf(resData.results[0].geometry.location.lng);
                    locat.isLong_Lat_Updated__c = true;
                    // locat.latitude = resData.results[0].geometry.location.lat;
                    //  locat.longitude = resData.results[0].geometry.location.lng;
                   // upsert locat;
                }catch(Exception e){
                    System.debug(e.getMessage() + e.getLineNumber());
                }
                
            }
        system.debug('updatedLocList'+updatedLocList);
        if(updatedLocList.size() > 0){
            Database.update(updatedLocList, false);
        }
       // return locat;
    }
    public class res{
        public List<results> results;
    }
    public class results{
        public geometry geometry;
    }
    public class geometry{
        public  location location;
    }
    public class location{
        public String lat;
        public string lng;
    }
}
```

Kindly suggest some solution

Comment: An advice would it to either convert it to queueable and chain it to make max 100 callouts per execution context, or update logic near trigger to dispatch to a future call <100 records in order not to hit the same limit of amount of callouts

Comment: reduce the batch size?

Answer (score 2):

The error message is clear that you cannot make more than 100 calls in Transaction (Tx) context. Each time your future job runs, it starts a new Tx context and that execution can make max 100 calls.

Couple of suggestions.

1. Update calling method to batch `locationlist` to max 100 items and submit multiple future jobs.
2. Or convert this Future job to Queueable and after 100 calls, re-submit to itself with remaining items in the list to daisy chain the calls.

Comment: N.B. 100 callouts could theoretically run into total callout time Limit per transaction before hitting 100 callouts. I tend to use custom metadata to define the # callouts per Txn so this can be configured based on observed experience

Comment: Agree on that, depending on what it is during, it could run into total callout time or max apex cpu time.